# Get invalid node libxml

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument, libxml2

I'm using DOMDocument's schemavalidate method to validate a XML and libxml_get_errors to get all the errors. Is there a way to 'find' the element in the XML that causes an error? Currently the libXMLError only contains a linenumber. I don't think it's possible to query the element by linenumber using Xpath.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Xpath does not have it but DOMNode has: [`DOMNode::getLineNo`](http://php.net/domnode.getlineno) - perhaps this helps a little? Also if you add working example code to your question could be useful, too. AFAIK you need to write that functionality your own.

Comment: @hakre; Thanks for the reply. Yes, that could be an option but that would mean I should loop through all DOMNodes to determine their lineNo. Does anyone have more creative solutions :) ?

Comment: Well another alternative is to go through with XMLReader. It also has the errors and then stops so you would have the line directly. But it's more work to implement so I suggested the other variant first.

Comment: Also the error message may help, because the line num is in it (I know that's hakish, but it worked for me over years)